# Webscraping - How to get a specific element on a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am beginner in Python, i'm trying to get a date from a website for a project. This is the source code from HTML:

```
< div class = bcaHz >
    < span >
        <a href="/Profile/E6238FHname">name</a> 
        wrote a review 14 Mar
    </span>
```

How can I get the `14 Mar` or `wrote a review 14 Mar` only?

this is the full block of the code:

def processPage(soupObj, hotelID, extractedDF):

```
# Read reviews
reviews = soupObj.find_all("div", {"data-test-target": "reviews-tab"})

# Get the list of reviews
reviewsList = reviews[0].select("div[class*=cWwQK]")

# Loop thru each review
for i in range(0,len(reviewsList)):
    
    # Get Rating
    r1 = reviewsList[i].select("span[class*=ui_bubble_rating]")
    r2 = r1[0]["class"][1]
    reviewRating = int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, r2)))/10

    # Get review date 
    reviewDate = reviewsList[i].select("span[class*=bcaHz]")
```

It runs and extracts to an Excel but the column for review date is empty.

Comment: (1) Using any python libraries (2) Did you check that `reviewDate` is actually collecting the required data ? Please always share enough code to reproduce your errors.

Comment: sorry ! updated the question with the full block !

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """
<div class="bcaHz">
    <span>
        <a href="/Profile/E6238FHname">name</a> 
        wrote a review 14 Mar
    </span>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")

data = "".join(
    soup.select_one(".bcaHz span").find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
).strip()

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
wrote a review 14 Mar
```

---

To get only date, you can use afterwards:

```py
import re

data = re.search(r"\d.*", data)[0]
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
14 Mar
```